# R (Loop) Error in data frame, replacement has x rows, data has y rows

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, dataframe

So I'm working on a project that requires me to create multiple plots using air quality data given for 30+ seperate days/files.

I've learned and copied from a person who has already done it but somehow I'm having problems integrating it with the data I have, any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#---START OF THE FOR LOOP---
all_dates = seq(begin_date, end_date, 1)
for (j in 1:length(all_dates)) {
  selected_date = all_dates[j]

  #read data from the file with (id, lat, lon, elev, value... enter your attributes here) columns
  datapointfile = paste(variable,"_",aggregate,"_",format.Date(selected_date,"%Y-%m-%d"),".txt",sep="")

  datapoints_wgs84 = read.table(datapointfile, header=TRUE)
  coordinates(datapoints_wgs84) = ~lon + lat
  proj4string(datapoints_wgs84) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
  datapoints <- spTransform(datapoints_wgs84, CRS(projection))

  #INTERPOLATION STARTS HERE!

  #calculate linear regression intercept and slope(observ=B+A*elev)
  observlm <- lm(value ~ elev, datapoints)
  datapoints$res = observlm$residuals

  #calculate observ value raster using linear model (elevation / observ value)
  intercept = observlm$coefficients[1]
  slope = observlm$coefficients[2]
  regression_grid <- intercept + srtm * slope


  #interpolate the residuals using idw
  idw_test = idw(res~1, datapoints, defaultgrid)
  residual_grid = raster(idw_test, "var1.pred")

  #add regression grid and residuals
  finalgrid <- regression_grid + residual_grid

  #INTERPOLATION ENDS HERE!


  #START OF THE PLOT!  
  layout = list(vrstvastudyarea)
  outfile = paste("Output", selected_date, ".png", sep="")
  png(filename = outfile, width = 1500, height = 1000, pointsize = 25, bg = "white", res = 150)
  nadpis = paste("Air Quality", selected_date)
  print(spplot(finalgrid, at=intervaly, col.regions = grid_colors, 
               sp.layout=layout, 
               main=list(nadpis, cex=2, col="black", font=2), 
               colorkey=list(at=intervaly2, labels = list( at=intervaly2, cex = 1.5, labels = intervaly, lab = intervaly2), space="bottom")))
  dev.off()
  #END OF THE PLOT!



#---OUTPUT---

[inverse distance weighted interpolation]
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, name, value = c(8.66783923397599,  : 
  replacement has 14 rows, data has 18
```

So basically instead of getting 30+ outputs I get 1 output (for some reason!?) and then I get the error which is given above as the output :/. If I got no output I would understand but given first data file and the second data file has almost no difference in format I should not have any error in formatting...

Couple more information I think that might help solving the issue are:

1. My data files look like this:

"id"    "elev"  "lon"   "lat"   "value"

Afyon   1027    30.54277778 38.75166667 108.2903226

Aydin   54  27.83666667 37.84027778 122.7096774

.

.

.

2. And the person I copied the data from has a data as the following:

"id"    "lat"   "lon"   "elev"  "value"

2   50.69205    15.72876    816 37

3   49.735  16.0336 737 19

.

.

.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently it was caused by my data having some "NA" entries in it. Fixed it by giving them appropriate values. Although I'm still clueless how the code would've worked if I would like it to work with those NA values included.